# Is it possible to access files "shadowed" by a mount?

Tags: linux, mount

In Linux, is there a way to access files on a mounted filesystem that have been "shadowed" when another file system was mounted over a subdirectory?

E.g.

```
cd /
mkdir /foo
touch /foo/bar
mount /dev/sda1 /foo
# now, can I still get to /foo/bar on the / filesystem?
```

The solution of my dreams would not require elevated permissions or be specific to a certain file system, but I'll take whatever scraps I can get without risking a corrupted file system.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the mount command to access the underlying filesystem.

```
$ mkdir /mnt/root
$ sudo mount --bind / /mnt/root
$ cat /mnt/root/foo/bar
```

There is no issue with corruption with doing this, but it does require permission to mount the file system.

Comment: +1, I thought that `mount --bind` was the answer. But I wasn't sure.

Comment: +0.95, I completely forgot about binds being nonrecursive by default. However, last time I bindmounted / elsewhere, I could not umount it without rebooting; might have been some GUI component grabbing it though. Have you tested that?

Comment: Thanks! I thought about bind mounts for a second, but thought they'd work based on path name rewriting and thus be recursive...

Comment: I don't understand why it is accepted. After I mount over `/`, `/mnt/root` points to newly mounted location, not previous one. Linux Mint 20.2. The solution could be hard linking, but it is not allowed on my system, might require tweeking the kernel something...

Comment: @alexie It was accepted because it works, it is the purpose of the --bind directive. Are you perhaps doing something different to the OP?

Comment: Note to clumsy folks like me: if you mount your entire filesystem to a folder before performing an `rsync --delete` to the filesystem to update it (embedded system in my case) - you will wipe your filesystem. /facepalm. But thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have root, you can `mount --move` the mounted filesystem on top of a temporary directory, then move it back afterwards.

```
mkdir /bar
mount --move /foo /bar
```

---

Having root also allows accessing the underlying block devices, if any, directly. For ext4, you can use `debugfs` to export files.

*Read-only* access can *never* corrupt the filesystem.

---

Directories can have handles, or file descriptors, obtained for them. The "current directory" is a handle too, not a path. If you have a handle to a directory, you can access files inside even if that location has been mounted over. This does not need special privileges, only special preparation.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but it's the first one that pops up on Google. There is another way to access the 'hidden' filesystem, using a separate [unshare](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html). It creates a separate namespace with different mounts, and runs *something* in there. (It's also possible to make it persistent - see the manpage.)

```bash
mkdir /tmp/above /tmp/below
touch /tmp/above/a /tmp/below/b
mount -o bind /tmp/above /tmp/below
ls below
unshare --mount sh -c 'umount /tmp/below ; ls /tmp/below'
```

The first `ls` wil see 'a', and the second will see 'b'.

It does require elevated permissions, but should work on any kind of filesystem.